# Hint/guidance on proving $a^x \leq 1 + (a-1)x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to prove that $a^x \leq 1 + (a-1)x$ for $a \geq 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$. Can someone please give me a hint or guidance on how to approach this in general?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Binomial series:  $(1+(a-1))^x=1+(a-1)x+\cdots$

Comment: *Hint*: The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+,\quad \xi\mapsto \xi^x$ is concave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show it using the concavity of $\ln$.

First, note that your inequaliy is equivalent to

$$x\ln a \leq \ln(1+(a-1)x)$$

Now, noting that $x\in [0,1]$ you have

$$x\ln a = x\ln a + (1-x)\underbrace{\ln 1}_{=0}\stackrel{concavity}{\leq}\underbrace{\ln (x\cdot a + (1-x)\cdot 1)}_{ = \ln(1+(a-1)x)}$$

Done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  This is tailor made for the binomial theorem (Taylor series could probably also be used), because we have $a^x=(1+(a-1))^x$ as @J.W.Tanner notes. To use the binomial theorem note that it holds for fractional exponents, then take limits and use continuity (in case $x$ is irrational).